# Error when executing nix-shell in plutus-apps

Tags: plutus, nix, nix-shell, nixos

I am getting...

```
error: experimental Nix feature 'flakes' is disabled; use '--extra-experimental-features flakes' to override
```

...when trying to run `nix-shell` from `plutus-apps` repo.

Does anybody know how I can enable `flakes`?

I am using the latest commit `7952b9d30d15779a7fd8103bdbc9612d5df18ec2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of fixing this issue:

**Temporary**

Add `--experimental-features 'nix-command flakes'` when calling the `nix-shell` command.

**Permanent**

Edit either `~/.config/nix/nix.conf` or `/etc/nix/nix.conf` and add:

```
experimental-features = nix-command flakes
```

For more information you can refer to: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/#nix-1

Comment: This is in plutus-apps nix config https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/#nix-1

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the answer to include that link instead of the one from Nix.